# How to return success after running a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

I'm really new to both Perl and Ajax and I was wondering how do I return a message for ajax to know if a script ran successfully and run a success script after knowing the perl script was successful.

On my main html page I have an ajax script like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.archive-button', function(){
    var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');
    var archiveaddress = '/user/notices/archivenotice/' + notice_id;
    $.post(archiveaddress, {notice_id: notice_id});
});
```

which send its to the archivenotice.html page which runs a Perl script which just marks the time the notice was read.

```
my $update_needed = 0;
unless ($notice->read_on()) {
    $notice->read_on(scalar localtime);
    $update_needed = 1;
}
```

What should I add to the Perl script on the archivenotice.html pages so that the ajax on my main html page knows the script ran successfully and initiate another script called "successful"

Comment: In your Perl script, simply `print` whatever you want to send back to the jQuery `.post`. Then grab that info in your `.post` "success" method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a very visual person. Would you mind showing me an example?

Comment: Adding to what @bloodyKnuckles said, at the end of your perl script do something like `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"; print qq{"status":"success","updateNeeded":"$update_needed"};` so you can a retrieve a specific response from perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.archive-button', function(){
   var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');
   var archiveaddress = '/user/notices/archivenotice/' + notice_id;
   $.post(archiveaddress, {notice_id: notice_id}).done(function() {
      alert( "update success" );
   });
});
```

Comment: This does not determine if the Perl was truly successful, just if the AJAX completed successfully round trip.

Answer (score 3):

Open a channel of communication between your main.html page and archivenotice Perl script.

main.html

```
$(document).on('click', '.archive-button', function(){
    var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');
    var archiveaddress = '/user/notices/archivenotice/' + notice_id;
    $.post(archiveaddress, {notice_id: notice_id}, function( data ) {
        if ( data ) { alert('Update needed!'); }
        else { alert('Update not needed.'); }
    });
});
```

archivenotice

```
my $update_needed = 0;
unless ($notice->read_on()) {
    $notice->read_on(scalar localtime);
    $update_needed = 1;
}
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print $update_needed;
exit;
```

Comment: The content-type should always be included

Comment: Nice call. :) Updated.